# jQuery radio button show div

Tags: jquery, html

Hey guys, what function could I use to say, if this radio button is checked show this 'div'. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form id='form-id'>
    <input id='watch-me' name='test' type='radio' /> Show Div<br />
    <input name='test' type='radio' /><br />
    <input name='test' type='radio' />
</form>
<div id='show-me' style='display:none'>Hello</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#form-id').change(function() {
    if ($('#watch-me').attr('checked')) {
        $('#show-me').show();
    } else {
        $('#show-me').hide();
    }
});
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/wmKGd/

**UPDATE 25.01.2013**
After Upgrading from jQuery Library 1.8.x to 1.9.x
Please use instead of
jQuery Library 1.8.x

```
jQuery('#some-id').attr('checked')
```

jQuery Library 1.9.x

```
jQuery('#some-id').prop('checked')
```

You can see it with updated script in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/9XXRY/

Comment: thanks, this helped me too! appreciate the 25.01.13 update as well.

Answer (score 3):

I liked @tinifni's jsfiddle.  Here's one with 3 divs that show or hide depending on the radio.

http://jsfiddle.net/dbwest/wmKGd/572/

```
$('#form-id').change(function() {
    if ($('#watch-me').attr('checked')) {
        $('#show-me').show();
    } else {
        $('#show-me').hide();
    }
    if ($('#watch-me2').attr('checked')) {
        $('#show-me2').show();
    } else {
        $('#show-me2').hide();
    }
    if ($('#watch-me3').attr('checked')) {
        $('#show-me3').show();
    } else {
        $('#show-me3').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("myradiobuttonselector").change(function () {
  if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
    $("mydivSelector").show();
  }
  else {
   $("mydivSelector").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. Replace “mydiv” with the id of your radio button and “content1” with the content you want to show/hide.

Post some html if you need further help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#content1').hide();

   $('a').click(function(){
      $('#content1').show('slow');
   });

   $(‘#mydiv’).click(function(){
      $('#content1').hide('slow');
   })
});
```

Rick